# How to: Conditionally format a <td>, that is generated via MySQL query, based on content and using PHP/JavaScript

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, format, conditional-statements

I have a database table that contains:

```
Industry risk
--------------
      A
      B
      C
```

And so on. I use `query.php` to generate a dynamic table to `index.php` and refresh it automatically using AJAX. The data is pulled with:

`$sql="SELECT * FROM scoreboard";`

And the table generated with:

```
// Construct the table

echo "<table id='querytable'>\n";
```

The result is processed by `query.js` and displayed in `index.php` with: `<div id="querydiv"></div>`. So far, so good. Now for the tricky part. I want to conditionally format the background of the `<td>` based on the content, so that if it contains "A" then  `background-color:red;`. The `<td>` are generated like so:

```
// Construct the array

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    echo '<tr>'."\n";
    echo "<td align='center'>{$row['codcliente']}</td>\n" . "<td align='center'>{$row['nombre']}</td>\n" . "<td align='center'>{$row['ejecutivo']}</td>\n" . "<td align='center'>{$row['banca_as400']}</td>\n" . "<td align='center'>{$row['banca_real']}</td>\n" . "<td align='right'>$&nbsp;".number_format($row['ingresos'], 2)."</td>\n" . "<td align='center'>{$row['ciiu']}</td>\n" . "<td align='center'>{$row['division']}</td>\n" . "<td align='center'>{$row['actividad']}</td>\n" . "<td align='center'>{$row['riesgo_industria']}</td>\n" . "<td align='center'>{$row['riesgo_cliente']}</td>\n" . "<td align='center'>{$row['fecha']}</td>\n" . "<td align='center'>{$row['analista']}</td>\n";
    echo '</tr>'."\n";
}
echo "</table>\n";
```

I made a JavaScript file called `highlight.js` which contains:

```
$(function() {
            $("#querytable td:contains('A')").css('background-color','#C0504D'),
            $("#querytable td:contains('B')").css('background-color','#FDE480'),
            $("#querytable td:contains('C')").css('background-color','#9BBB59');
            });
```

And I try to call it from `query.php` using:

```
// Load higlighting syntax

echo "<script type='text/javascript' src='highlight.js'></script>";
```

but nothing happens. I've tried giving the `<div>` tag and id and calling the JavaScript from `index.php` (since it has HTML and a `<head>` tag), but that didn't work either.

Is there anyway to do this? What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Additional info. Contents of `query.js`:

```
// Customize these settings

var seconds = 2;
var divid = "querydiv";
var url = "query.php";

// Refreshing the DIV

function refreshdiv(){

// The XMLHttpRequest object

var xmlHttp;
try{
xmlHttp=new XMLHttpRequest(); // Firefox, Opera 8.0+, Safari
}
catch (e){
try{
xmlHttp=new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP"); // Internet Explorer
}
catch (e){
try{
xmlHttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
catch (e){
alert("Your browser does not support AJAX.");
return false;
}
}
}

// Timestamp for preventing IE caching the GET request

fetch_unix_timestamp = function()
{
return parseInt(new Date().getTime().toString().substring(0, 10))
}

var timestamp = fetch_unix_timestamp();
var nocacheurl = url+"?t="+timestamp;

// The code...

xmlHttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
if(xmlHttp.readyState==4){
document.getElementById(divid).innerHTML=xmlHttp.responseText;
setTimeout('refreshdiv()',seconds*1000);
}
}
xmlHttp.open("GET",nocacheurl,true);
xmlHttp.send(null);
}

// Start the refreshing process

var seconds;
window.onload = function startrefresh(){
setTimeout('refreshdiv()',seconds*1000);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why don't you just use css?

Add the value to the `class` attribute on the `td` then set the rules in css.

Add the class like `class='CONTENTS'`:

```
echo "<td align='center' class='{$row['codcliente']}'> ...
```

And then replace your jQuery code with a stylesheet:

```
#querytable td.A {background-color : #C0504D; }
#querytable td.B {background-color : #FDE480; }
#querytable td.C {background-color : #9BBB59; }
```

In your example the content was simple and valid css, if the contents had spaces  or started with numbers you would need to transform them to valid css class names.

(edit, I copied the js code into my css without fixing the syntax)

Comment: or add the class to the table row: <tr class='{$row['codcliente']}'> then #querytable tr.A td {...}

Comment: Thanks @joe, but I'm a bit lost. Is `#querytable td.A {'background-color','#C0504D' }` defined in `style.css`? (I use a style sheet already).

Comment: You can have multiple css rules for the same selector.  I just edited the css rules above because they were copied from your js.  Just add them to the existing stylesheet.  They will only affect `td`s inside of `#querytable`.  

I'm not sure I got the semantics right from your variable names, if the coloring applies to whole rows, set it on the `tr` and modify the css rules as described by Tank above.

Comment: Quick question @joeshmo, how would I go about setting a rule with two words? `#querytable td.Very high {background-color : #E46D0A;
}`

Comment: I would set `class='very-high'` and then set the rule with `.very-high`, but if you're going to keep it two words, css considers this two separate classes, you can still use them that way, the syntax is `#querytable td.Very.high`

Comment: @joe It actually works if you only put "Very" in the `#querytable td.Very`, but regarding your comment, does the period after "Very" in `#querytable td.Very.high` work like a space?

Comment: `.Very` would work there, but by coincidence.  The css selector `td.Very.high` could be read as "td elements with both 'Very' and 'high' classes".

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that highlight.js runs too early.  It runs immediately, dutifully looking for all matching elements and coloring them, but, alas, the asynchronous query hasn't yet inserted the content to be matched.

It may appear to be instantaneous, but in fact (I believe) you have an order of operations problem.

So to solve it, you need to run the coloring code after the queried content has been injected into the page.  This would happen as part of the `$.ajax` or `$.load` call (not specified in the problem description) that you use to bring in the query.php content.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks @jim, I added the contents of the JavaScript file, but I can't find `$.ajax` or `$.load` anywhere. Where would I place my coloring code?

Answer (score 1):

jimbojw explained to you why your code isn't working, you need to call the code in *highlight.js* **after** you update your table. He thought you were using jQuery for the AJAX part, but you aren't. So you have two options, change your code to use jQuery AJAX functions or call your highlight code from inside xmlHttp.onreadystatechange

```
xmlHttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
    if(xmlHttp.readyState==4){
        document.getElementById(divid).innerHTML=xmlHttp.responseText;
        setTimeout('refreshdiv()',seconds*1000);

        // call the code after updating the DOM tree
        $("#querytable td:contains('A')").css('background-color','#C0504D'),
        $("#querytable td:contains('B')").css('background-color','#FDE480'),
        $("#querytable td:contains('C')").css('background-color','#9BBB59');
    }
}
```